# Does XML::LibXML::Reader read HTML?

Tags: html, perl, xml-libxml

I didn't find anything about parsing HTML in the [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XMl-LibXML) documentation. And I tried to parse a HTML-site and it didn't work.
Is my conclusion, that XML::LibXML::Reader doesn't work with HTML right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it's really XHTML, then no.  XML is much more restrictive than HTML is, and XML parsers normally can't parse HTML.

[HTML::TokeParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TokeParser) (or its base class [HTML::PullParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::PullParser)) are the most similar to [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML::Reader) (but not all that similar).

You might want to look at [HTML-Tree](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Tree) for something similar to LibXML that does work with HTML.  There's also [HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML), which wraps an even more LibXML-compatible interface around HTML-Tree.

Answer (score 1):

No, but [HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML) implements a compatible interface on an HTML paser.